# Passing parameters separated by commas to << operator

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to `Eigen` advanced initialization for my container class.

i.e. in `main`, I want to fill an object of type `DynamicArray` as follows:

**main.cpp**

```
// Create 3 x 3 Dynamic array and fill with 0's
DynamicArray da(3, 3, 0);

da << 1, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,
      7, 8, 9;
```

The method I've used to try to accomplish this is:

**DynamicArray.hpp**

```
template <typename T>
class DynamicArray {

        // ...

public:

        // ...

    template <typename... Args,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<ArgPackSameTruth<
                                             std::is_convertible<Args, T>...>::value,
                                             T>::type
    > void operator<<(Args... x) {

        typename std::vector<T> arg_vect{std::forward<Args>(x)...};

        std::cout << arg_vect.size() << "\n";

        // Load contents of arg_vect into *this...

        return;
    }
}
```

When I compile `main.cpp`, I get a size of 1 for `arg_vect`, so only the first parameter is being taken in. How can I make sure all parameters are passed?

Thanks!

Comment: You may make your operator overload return `*this` so that it can become possible to chain `da << 1 << 2 //...` calls.

Comment: operator overloading doesn't magically change the number of operands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of operations is different from what you seem to think. If you have:

```
da << 1, 2, 3;
```

it is equivalent to (given free operators):

```
auto tmp1 = operator<<(da,1);
auto tmp2 = operator,(tmp1,2);
auto tmp3 = operator,(tmp2,3);
```

hence you'd need operators roughly like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct DynamicArray
{
};

DynamicArray& operator<<( DynamicArray& da, int i )
{
    std::cout << "<<" << i << std::endl;
    return da;
}

DynamicArray& operator,( DynamicArray& da, int i )
{
    std::cout << "," << i << std::endl;
    return da;
}

int main()
{
    DynamicArray da;
    da << 1, 2, 3,
          4, 5, 6,
          7, 8, 9;
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0890967ef2e6ca3b)

Of course you need to store the values somewhere, etc. Think about a design which allows this and consider adding an intermediate class to hold the values which is returned by `operator<<` and which works as both the first input parameter and the return type for `operator,`. The destructor of that class can be used to apply the collected intermediate data if needed.

Comment: Note that `da, 1,2,3,4,5` also puts numbers into `da`, which is not desired/

Answer (score 2):

`operator <<` only takes 1 argument. That's why the size is 1. The numbers after 1 are all unused. If you turn on `-Wall` you should get a warning about this.

I can think of 2 solutions.

**One** would be to simply enclose the numbers in braces `{...}` and let `operator <<` accept a `std::initializer_list<double>`

`void operator<< (std::initializer_list<double>);`

**Second** solution would be to have Dynamic array overload `operator,`and `operator<<`

Both `,` and `<<` would return a DynamicArray so that they could be chained.

```
DynamicArray& operator<<(double x){
    //Add x to the Dynarray
    return *this;
}
```

`operator,` Would do the same thing as `operator<<`

```
DynamicArray& operator, (double x){
    //Add x to the Dynarray
    return *this;
}
```

Here is a baisic example for `std::vector`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T>&
operator<<(std::vector<T>& x, T y)
{
    x.push_back(y);
    return x;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T>&
operator,(std::vector<T>& x, T y)
{
    x.push_back(y);
    return x;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> A;
    A << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;
    for(int x : A){
        std::cout << x << ",";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```